# How much disk space to install CentOS?

Tags: centos, java, disk-space-utilization

What is the minimum amount of diskspace a CentOS system, plus the java virtual machine, needs to be installed?

Desktop interface is not needed.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish with that system?

Comment: install many VMS to test some software

Answer (score 3, accepted):

4 GB should be sufficient for **/**. Add another 4 GB for **/var**. So in sum 8 GB should be enough (I use no swapspace).

That`s what I use as standard for our virtual CentOS 5 machines. They normally never hit the 80% mark in that setup.

Answer (score 1):

If you use [Fedora's AOS kickstart](https://fedorahosted.org/spin-kickstarts/browser/fedora-aos.ks) then you can get it down to under 500MB or so.